# Duplicate ajax content

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I have a problem with duplicates ajax content in jquery mobile (knockout).
The problem start when I call back button to start form and when I calling again all process.
Example code:

```html
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
                <a data-bind="click: headerBackBtn" data-role="button">Back</a>
                <h1>
                    Header title
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <form id="form" name="form" data-bind="visible: form">
                        <label for="name">Name:</label>
                        <input type="search" name="name" id="name"/>
                        <button data-bind="click: toFirstContent" data-icon="search">Search</button>
                </form>

                <!-- first content -->
                <div class="div-1" id="div-1" data-bind="visible: div-1">
                    <a data-bind="click: toSecondContent">
                        Link
                    </a>
                </div>

                <!-- second content -->
                <div class="div-2" id="div-2" data-bind="visible: div-2">
                    Text
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c">
                <h4>footer</h4>
            </div>
```

```js
    self.headerBackBtn = function () {
        if (self.div-2()) {
            self.div-2(false);
            self.div-1(true);
            return;
        }
        if (self.div-1()) {
            self.div-1(false);
            self.form(true);
            return;
        }
    };
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that div-1 and div-2 aren't valid javascript identifiers, is that just in your example code, or is this part of your actual code?

Comment: no div id is just for example you can put div1 or div2

Comment: So what is actually the problem? I can't see an ajax call in your code.

Comment: Ok my ajax call is next:
$.ajax({
            type: GET,
            url: url + method,
            data: data,
            async: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: jsonp,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                callback(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error);
            }
        });

Comment: For every click (data-bind: click) I create function where I call service and from that service call I getting good result. Maybe I ask some wrong question, but my ajax call is ok (I know/suppose because I put a valid data from json response into div-1 and div-2)..
Question is: How can I when I click on first back (self.div-2()) clear data in div-2, and when I click on 2nd back clear content from div-1.
I hope that question is now more clear for understanding.Tnx in advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution is http://api.jquery.com/remove/. For every element I put class="removeItem" and then call $(".removeItem").remove(), before I call function for getting new elements...